# How to prevent DPMS/screensaver from activating when gamepad used?

Tags: xorg, screensaver, dpms

If I use keyboard/mouse Xorg server understand that then computer involved into user input activity.

How to enable support for indicating user activity through gamepad so monitor suddenly doesn't turn off when I play game with gamepad.

Note that I don't ask about `xset -dpms s off`.

Comment: jfyi: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200149/110559

Comment: does the `xinput` detects gamepad as input device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to `xinput --list` as suggested by Alexander Barakin shown that my gamepad isn't handled by Xorg.

Games directly communicate with `/dev/input/js*` so Xorg doesn't know about any activity through gamepad.

Possible solutions:

- wrapper scripts around commands that `xset -dpms s off; COMMAND; xset +dpms s on`
- detecting X properties, like class/resource pattern names and running `xset ...`. It is possible to disable DPMS when application run if full-screen mode, etc.
- make CRON job that detect particular processes and disable DPMS

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/foresto/joystickwake is a python script meant to solve exactly this problem. It monitors joystick/gamepad inputs and runs (configurable) screensaver-inhibiting commands when there's activity and it hasn't run one in a certain (configurable) amount of time.